# How to create a new objectID in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I want to generate two different objectIds in mongoose schema. One for departureLocation and one for arrivalLocation and want to reference it later.
I imported the object id from mongoose like this

```
let id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
```

now I want to generate two different object ids like I said above

```
const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    location: {
      departureLocation: {
        name: {
          ref: "Location",
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        //want to create new object id here,
        subLocation: [String],
        _id: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
      arrivalLocation: {
        name: {
          ref: "Location",
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
         //want to create new object id here,
        subLocation: [String],
        _id: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    },
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    busId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Bus",
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will automatically create `_id` for an object in a schema. You do not need to create one. In this schema, there will be 4 automatically generated `_id`s one for `location`, one for `departureLocation`, one for `arrivalLocation`, and one for the overall schema.